# Compare a linq value (int) to an int List using where clause

Tags: linq, list, contains

I have a linq query which joins a couple of tables and returns the value into an object. The query was working fine, till i added a where clause to in. Aftre the where clause, my query returns null.

Here's the code:

```
List<Int32> resourceSupervisorIdList = new List<Int32>();

resourceSupervisorIdList.Add(searchCriteriaTimesheet.ResourceId);

foreach (resource res in allSubordinateResources)
{
    if (!resourceSupervisorIdList.Contains(res.id_resource))
        resourceSupervisorIdList.Add(res.id_resource);
}

using (tapEntities te = new tapEntities())
{
    var timesheetAll = (from tsh in te.timesheet_header
                        join rs in te.resources on tsh.id_resource equals rs.id_resource
                        join tsd in te.timesheet_detail on tsh.id_timesheet equals                   tsd.id_timesheet
                        where (resourceSupervisorIdList.Contains(rs.id_resource_supervisor))
                        select new TimesheetHeaderDetailsItem()
                        {
                            OrganizationId = rs.id_organization,
                            ProjectId = tsd.id_project,
                            StartDate = tsh.dte_period_start,
                            EndDate = tsh.dte_period_end,
                            ApprovedDate = tsh.dte_approved,
                            RejectedDate = tsh.dte_rejected,
                            SubmittedDate = tsh.dte_submitted,

                          });

    if (timesheetAll == null || timesheetAll.Count() == 0)
    {
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now, after adding the where clause, the code runs into the if condition. There are matching records in the table, but still i'm not able to get any records.

```
rs.id_resource_supervisor
```

is of type int in the mysql db.

Comment: Possible cause: you don't execute `timesheetAll` within the `using`. Side note: it's never `null`.

Comment: That code cannot compile, as timesheetAll is declared locally inside the using. It cannot be not visible at the if statement.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo in my question. Now i have updated the code. I had place the { wrongly in the question. Now i have corrected the code. So now, please recheck the code and provide me with some solution.

Comment: Check the generated SQL and see if it returns records when you execute it directly.

Comment: yes, it does return the records

Comment: @user3156366 Have you checked your `resourceSupervisorIdList` ?

Comment: Yes, the List does contain values, and the values are such that they do match the required criteria of where clause.

Comment: Ok, i got it. There was a problem with my query. I wasn't fetching the correct id. Sorry guys and thanks for helping.